# How to start interruption on certain key stroke assembly

Tags: assembly, interrupt, dos, x86-16

i want to write a program that prints constantly a number (variable) and when '+' is pressed the number will increase and when '-' is pressed the number will decrease, but i don't want the program to stop and wait for input, i want the interruption to start on the key stroke...
any ideas???
i tried to set "AH = 6" and int "21h", but then the program waits for input.
**i want the program to wait for the input while running**

```
org 100h 


mov ax, 127
array db "000", 0Dh,0Ah, 24h
temp    dw 10 

start:

followHeater:   
in ax, 125
push ax
mov bx, offset array
push bx
call my_print_num
mov dx, offset array
mov ah, 9
int 21h
in ax, 125
cmp ax, temp
mov ax, 1
jl heat:
mov ax, 0
jmp continue
heat:   
mov ax, 1
continue:
out 127, ax
jmp followHeater    

mov ah, 0
int 16h
ret    




jmp start  


proc my_print_num
    push bp
    mov bp, sp
    pusha  

    mov di, 10    
    mov si, 2
    mov cx, 3
    mov ax, [bp+6]
    mov bx, [bp+4]

    getNum:
    xor dx, dx                            
    div di
    add dl, '0'
    mov [bx+si], dl 
    dec si
    loop getNum

    popa
    mov sp, bp
    pop bp
    ret
endp my_print_num
```

Comment: int 21h/ah=0bh seems to check if input is available

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> org 100h 
>
> mov ax, 127
> array db "000", 0Dh,0Ah, 24h
> temp    dw 10 
>
> start:
> ```

The code is messed-up here! You have to **jump over the data**. (And the `mov ax,127` instruction is probably not what you want).

```
        org  100h

        jmp  Start
array   db   "000", 0Dh,0Ah, 24h
temp    dw   10 

start:
```

---

> **i want the program to wait for the input while running**

Why not use the BIOS keyboard functions? Function 01h tests if a key is available and returns immediately reporting the presence of a key in the ZeroFlag. If a key is available you receive a preview of it in `AX` but the key stays in the keyboard buffer. If `ZF=0` you use function 00h to actually retrieve the key. This won't take long since you know that there is a key waiting!

```
  mov ah,01h  ;TestKey
  int 16h
  jz  NoKey
  mov ah,00h  ;GetKey
  int 16h
  mov cx,1
  cmp al,'+'
  je  SetTemp
  neg cx
  cmp al, '-'
  je  SetTemp
  ; Here you can test for more keys!
NoKey:
  jmp followHeater
SetTemp:
  add temp,cx
  jmp followHeater
```

---

There's a severe error in your program. The *my_print_num* proc is called with 2 parameters on the stack. That's fine but you need to remove these from the stack also.
The **callee** removes the parameters if you write:

```
  ret  4
endp my_print_num
```

or the **caller** removes the parameters if you write:

```
call my_print_num
add  sp,4
```

---

Your logic to turn the heat on/off is too complicated.
Next code does the same:

```
  in   ax, 125
  cmp  ax, temp
  mov  ax, 1    ;Heat ON
  jl   heat
  dec  ax       ;Heat OFF
heat:   
  out 127, ax
```

Alternatively if you're allowed to use instructions that are better than 8086.

```
  in   ax, 125
  cmp  ax, temp
  setl al        ;Sets AL=1 if condition Less, else sets AL=0
  cbw            ;Makes AH=0
  out 127, ax
```